# Where does Debian/Kde defines locale for users

Tags: debian, kde, locale

My default locale is (`/etc/default/locale`):

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
#LANGUAGE=en_US:pt_PT
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_TIME="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_NAME="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_PT.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

However, after I login, my normal user locale is:

```
LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=pt_PT.utf8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_PT.utf8
LC_TIME=pt_PT.utf8
LC_COLLATE=pt_PT.utf8
LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.utf8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=pt_PT.utf8
LC_NAME=pt_PT.utf8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_PT.utf8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_PT.utf8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_PT.utf8
LC_ALL=
```

And my root user locale is:

```
LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=pt_PT.utf8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_PT.utf8
LC_TIME=pt_PT.utf8
LC_COLLATE=pt_PT.utf8
LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.utf8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=pt_PT.utf8
LC_NAME=pt_PT.utf8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_PT.utf8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_PT.utf8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.utf8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_PT.utf8
LC_ALL=
```

The only place where the default seems to be used is in TTY's (<kbd>ATL</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc).

So, where does Debian/Kde defines locale for users?